# Convolving an image with a mask displays an all white image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Very new to MatLab, just figuring some things out and had a question. I am basically trying to filter/blur an image using conv2() but I am getting an all white image when I am using imshow()

I am reading the image in with

```
testImage = imread('test.bmp');
```

This is a uint8 image of a grayscale.

I am trying to convolve the image with a 4 x 4 matrix.

```
fourByFour = ones(4);
```

When I actually execute, I am getting all white with imshow()

```
convolvedImage = conv2(testImage, fourByFour);
```

I should expect a filter placed on the image, not an entirely white one.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `imshow` expects values between 0 and 1. Anything above 1 is clipped to maximum intensity. The best solution is probably to divide `testImage` by `255` before convolution. Perhaps you should normalize the mask as well

Comment: I could convert it to a binary image beforehand, right? testImage = im2bw(testImage); Rather than dividing by 255.

Comment: `testImage=double(imread('test.bmp')); imagesc(conv2(testImage,ones(4,4)));`

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85The image is very distorted looking, is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your test image so I explain on an image. As the definition of `conv2` it returns the **two-dimensional** convolution. 
So please look at this little code:

```
clc;% clear the screen
clear all;% clear everything
close all;% close all figures

test = imread('test.bmp');
% read test image that is  .bmp format and size :294x294x3 and uint8.

fourByFour = ones(4); % define 4 * 4 matrix all ones

convolvedImage = conv2(test(:,:,1), fourByFour);
%apply the ones matrix on image but to use conv2 on this image we apply on one of channels

figure, imshow(convolvedImage,[])
```

This is my command window, out put:
[image]

I'm using MAtlab 2017a, and if I use `conv2(test, fourByFour);` instead of `conv2(test(:,:,1), fourByFour);` ,the error is :

```
Error using conv2
N-D arrays are not supported.
```

So we should attention to class type and dimensions. And one more thing, in your command window please type `edit conv2` you can read the details of this function and how to use it, but never edit it:). Thanks

Comment: Thanks, this helped! Got it. Accepted your answer, too.

Answer (score -1):

```
test = imread('test.bmp');
% read test image that is  .bmp format and size :294x294x3 and uint8.

fourByFour = ones(4); 
% define 4 * 4 matrix all ones
test=rgb2gray(test);
% convert colorimage into gray
convolvedImage = conv2(double(test), double(fourByFour));
%perform the convolution
figure, imshow(convolvedImage,[])
% display the image
```

Comment: I will explain why someone downvoted your post: we don’t appreciate all-code answers, answers should answer the question, which means explaining how and why a particular piece of code addresses the problem. You can improve your code by explaining what you added to OP’s code and why that makes a difference.